# Have a custom hook run an API call only once in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a custom hook in my React application which uses a GET request to fetch some data from the MongoDB Database. In one of my components, I'm reusing the hook twice, each using different functions that make asynchronous API calls.

While I was looking at the database logs, I realized each of my GET requests were being called twice instead of once. As in, each of my hooks were called twice, making the number of API calls to be four instead of two. I'm not sure why that happens; I'm guessing the async calls result in re-renders that aren't concurrent, or there's somewhere in my component which is causing the re-render; not sure.

Here's what shows up on my MongoDB logs when I load a component:

[image: MongoDB log]

I've tried passing an empty array to limit the amount of time it runs, however that prevents fetching on reload. Is there a way to adjust the custom hook to have the API call run only once for each hook?

Here is the custom hook which I'm using:

```js
const useFetchMongoField = (user, id, fetchFunction) => {
  const [hasFetched, setHasFetched] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (!user) return;
      try {
        let result = await fetchFunction(user.email, id);
        setData(result);
        setHasFetched(true);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      }
    };

    if (data === null) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [user, id, fetchFunction, data]);

  return { data, hasFetched, error };
};
```

This is one of the components where I'm re-using the custom hook twice. In this example, `getPercentageRead` and `getNotes` are the functions that are being called twice on MongoDB (two `getPercentageRead` calls and two `getNotes` calls), even though I tend to use each of them once.

```js
const Book = ({ location }) => {
  const { user } = useAuth0();
  const isbn = queryString.parse(location.search).id;

  const { data: book, hasFetched: fetchedBook } = useFetchGoogleBook(isbn);
  const { data: read, hasFetched: fetchedPercentageRead } = useFetchMongoField(
    user,
    isbn,
    getPercentageRead
  );
  const { data: notes, hasFetched: fetchedNotes } = useFetchMongoField(
    user,
    isbn,
    getNotes
  );

  if (isbn === null) {
    return <RedirectHome />;
  }
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Header header="Book" subheader="In your library" />

      {fetchedBook && fetchedPercentageRead && (         
        <BookContainer
          cover={book.cover}
          title={book.title}
          author={book.author}
          date={book.date}
          desc={book.desc}
          category={book.category}
          length={book.length}
          avgRating={book.avgRating}
          ratings={book.ratings}
          language={book.language}
          isbn={book.isbn}
          username={user.email}
          deleteButton={true}
          redirectAfterDelete={"/"}
        >
          <ReadingProgress
            percentage={read}
            isbn={book.isbn}
            user={user.email}
          />          
        </BookContainer>        
      )}

      {!fetchedBook && (
        <Wrapper minHeight="50vh">
          <Loading
            minHeight="30vh"
            src={LoadingIcon}
            alt="Loading icon"
            className="rotating"
          />
        </Wrapper>
      )}
      <Header header="Notes" subheader="All your notes on this book">
        <AddNoteButton
          to="/add-note"
          state={{
            isbn: isbn,
            user: user,
          }}
        >
          <AddIcon color="#6b6b6b" />
          Add Note
        </AddNoteButton>
      </Header>
      {fetchedNotes && (
        <NoteContainer>
          {notes.map((note) => {
            return (
              <NoteBlock
                title={note.noteTitle}
                date={note.date}
                key={note._noteID}
                noteID={note._noteID}
                bookID={isbn}
              />
            );
          })}
          {notes.length === 0 && (
            <NoNotesMessage>
              You don't have any notes for this book yet.
            </NoNotesMessage>
          )}
        </NoteContainer>
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: GET is called twice because you use the hook 2 times. Remove 1 hook and you will see GET called once.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito OP is aware of this, and asking how to make the fetch in the hook only run once despite the hook being used more than once

Comment: The dependency array of `useEffect` determines when the function passed to it is called. If any of the referenced elements changes, the function runs again. Remove `data` and `fetchFunction`.

Comment: Yes this is the point...

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito OP's question is perfectly reasonable

Comment: `getPercentageRead` and `getNotes` are two different fetchFunctions, so I would expect that both need to be fetched. Currently your question is unclear. Do you want only one of those functions to be fetched? are both fetched twice? so you see four requests?

Comment: @Martin The second one. I see four requests instead of two.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I've edited my question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue.

The problem was I was assuming the `user` object  was remaining the same across renders, but some of its properties did in fact change. I was only interested in checking the `email` property of this object which doesn't change, so I only passed `user?.email` to the dependency array which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written your fetch functionality in your custom hook `useFetchMongoField` you have no flag to indicate that a request was already issued and you are currently just waiting for the response. So whenever any property in your `useEffect` dependency array changes, your request will be issued a second time, or a third time, or more. As long as no response came back.
You can just set a bool flag when you start to send a request, and check that flag in your `useEffect` before sending a request.

It may be the case that `user` and `isbn` are not set initially, and when they are set they each will trigger a re-render, and will trigger a re-evalution of your hook and will trigger your `useEffect`.